# Python dictionary extract data from two dictionaries and insert in new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set, dictionary-comprehension

I am a Python beginner and am struggling with working with dictionaries.

I have the dictionaries routesAndID and findOutPlane:

```
routesAndID = {('Sydney', 'Dubai'): 3, ('New York', 'Los Angeles'): 2, ('Zurich', 'Singapore'): 0}

findOutPlane = {('Sydney', 'Dubai'): 'Airplane', ('New York', 'Los Angeles'): 'Helicopter', ('Zurich', 'Singapore'): 'Jet'}
```

I need to extract the Aircraft and the corresponding ID on match of routes (depending on routes, the aircraft can be identified). I need the following output:

```
newdict = { "Airplane": 3, "Helicopter": 2, "Jet": 0 }
```

Would anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `newdict` from the values of `findOutPlane` matched with the value from `routesAndID` corresponding to the key from `findOutPlane`:

```py
newdict = { value : routesAndID.get(key, -1) for key, value in findOutPlane.items() }
```

Output:

```
{'Airplane': 3, 'Helicopter': 2, 'Jet': 0}
```

Note I've set a default value of `-1` for the fetch from `routesAndID` (using `routesAndID.get(key, -1)`) in case the key from `findOutPlane` is not present. If that will not be the case, you can simply use `routesAndID[key]` instead i.e.

```py
newdict = { value : routesAndID[key] for key, value in findOutPlane.items() }
```

Comment: @SashSinha fair comment. I've changed it to -1. That seems unlikely to be used in real life

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [`dict comprehension`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/):

```
>>> route_to_id = {
...     ('Sydney', 'Dubai'): 3,
...     ('New York', 'Los Angeles'): 2,
...     ('Zurich', 'Singapore'): 0
... }
>>> route_to_aircraft = {
...     ('Sydney', 'Dubai'): 'Airplane',
...     ('New York', 'Los Angeles'): 'Helicopter',
...     ('Zurich', 'Singapore'): 'Jet'
... }
>>> aircraft_to_id = {
...   aircraft: route_to_id[route]
...   for route, aircraft in route_to_aircraft.items()
... }
>>> aircraft_to_id
{'Airplane': 3, 'Helicopter': 2, 'Jet': 0}
```

If there could be multiple routes with the same aircraft type you could utilize [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> route_to_id = {
...     ('Sydney', 'Dubai'): 3,
...     ('New York', 'Los Angeles'): 2,
...     ('Zurich', 'Singapore'): 0,
...     ('Auckland', 'San Francisco'): 4
... }
>>> route_to_aircraft = {
...     ('Sydney', 'Dubai'): 'Airplane',
...     ('New York', 'Los Angeles'): 'Helicopter',
...     ('Zurich', 'Singapore'): 'Jet',
...     ('Auckland', 'San Francisco'): 'Airplane'
... }
>>> aircraft_to_ids = defaultdict(list)
>>> for route, aircraft in route_to_aircraft.items():
...     aircraft_to_ids[aircraft].append(route_to_id[route])
... 
>>> dict(aircraft_to_ids)
{'Airplane': [3, 4], 'Helicopter': [2], 'Jet': [0]}
```